# WinAPI File In-/Output with std::strings instead of char arrays?

Tags: c++, winapi, file, stdstring, readfile

due to performance reasons I didn't feel like using fstream for just one time. Seems like a very bad idea to use WinAPI functions with a **std::string** instead of a plain char array. All in all I would like you to tell me why the following snippet just won't work (empty stBuffer stays empty) and what I'd need to do to get it fixed.

Thanks in advance!

```
std::size_t Get(const std::string &stFileName, std::string &stBuffer)
{
    HANDLE    hFile        = ::CreateFileA(stFileName.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    DWORD    dwBytesRead    = 0;

    if(hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DWORD    dwFileSize    = ::GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);

        stBuffer.reserve(dwFileSize + 1);
        ::ReadFile(hFile, &stBuffer[0], dwFileSize, &dwBytesRead, NULL);
        stBuffer[dwFileSize] = '\0';
        ::CloseHandle(hFile);
    }

    return dwBytesRead;
}
```

Comment: I don't see a problem with using std::strings with winAPI. I'm doing it in my project.

Comment: While with VCs (and i think all major compilers) standard libraries `std::string` has a contigous buffer, this is not guaranteed by C++03. C++0x will guarantee that and until then `std::vector<char>` would be the *"clean"* solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a `std::string` can contain embedded `'\0'` characters, it has to keep track of its own length in a separate way.
Your problem is that `std::string::reserve()` does not change the length of the string. It just pre-allocates some memory for the string to grow into. The solution is to use `std::string::resize()` and let the WinAPI function overwrite the string contents.

As a side-note: Currently, it is not guaranteed that `std::string` uses a contiguous buffer, but to my knowledge, all current implementations do use a contiguous buffer and it will be a requirement in the next standard.

Comment: Thanks **a lot** for explaining!

Answer (score 1):

Consider difference between `reserve()` and `resize()` members. So the solution would be:

```
stBuffer.resize(dwFileSize + 1);
```

Comment: Uhm, then it should be `.resize(dwFileSize)` - the `+1` is superficial.

Comment: @Dummy00001 - the code is written to explicitly null-terminate the file contents. Unless this is wrong then the +1 is needed.

Comment: @Steve: Oops. You are *right*. The `'\0'` termination is also wrong in the original code: `std::string` doesn't need that.

Comment: With respect, it's not for you to decide whether that's wrong or not. As noted elsewhere std::string can contain embedded null characters.